# spark dataset encoder for kafka avro decoder message

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, avro

import spark.implicits._
  val ds1 = spark
    .readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    .option("subscribe", "test")
    .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
    .load()
    .as[KafkaMessage]
    .select($"value".as[Array[Byte]])
    .map(msg=>{

```
  val byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(msg)
  val datumReader:DatumReader[GenericRecord] = new SpecificDatumReader[GenericRecord](messageSchema)
  val dataFileReader:DataFileStream[GenericRecord]  = new DataFileStream[GenericRecord](byteArrayInputStream, datumReader)

  while(dataFileReader.hasNext) {
    val userData1: GenericRecord = dataFileReader.next()

    userData1.asInstanceOf[org.apache.avro.util.Utf8].toString
  }
})
```

Error:
Error:(49, 9) Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
    .map(msg=>{

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are trying to to do map/transformations on dataset in structured streaming, it is expected to associate with an appropriate encoder.

Tor primitive data types, implicit encoders are provided by spark:

```
import spark.implicits._
```

Where as for other types you need to provide manually.

So here you can either use implicit encoders:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

implicit def kryoEncoder[A](implicit ct: ClassTag[A]) = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[A](ct)
```

... or you can define your encoder which is associated with the data being processed within map function.